# Looking for a Hadoop-like solution at a smaller scale

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, infinispan

We have a database of about 1000 GB (thousand Gigabytes) and we are considering Hadoop to carry out time series analyses. Problem is that Hadoop takes some time to get into and for the size of our database Hadoop is actually even an oversized solution. My question is whether anyone knows a solution similar for Hadoop at a smaller scale. It also needs to have some SQL-like query language. Only thing that comes to my mind is JBoss Infinispan. But I wanted to check out whether there are other known solutions.

Comment: What kind of data do you store ?

Comment: Well, the data is highly relational and connected in many ways. Man that was a quick response ... ;-).

Comment: I should add that it is about data mining and not about MapReduce.

Comment: What is the abstract goal? using data-mining can be separated from the application (or actually should be) hence, depending on your problem (which might be easy to implement) you might get a better answer

Comment: @mandouh: Well the abstract goal is to run all kind of queries against monthly or yearly snapshots of the database. I don't think MapReduce can ever be used for something, because the data is so much interconnected and cannot be isolated into separate swimming lanes.

Comment: @OliverPlow, often Hadoop is used with different tools after the ET (or ETL) are carried out, thus reducing the number of joins and allowing large, possibly column-based schemas without being hindered by highly relational schemas.  As an aside: your question doesn't have a single, objective answer and therefore isn't really great for StackOverflow.

Comment: @OliverPlow - take a good look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176949/finding-an-optimum-learning-rule-for-an-ann/14178951#14178951) and let me know if any is applicable in your case!

Comment: @mandouh: I think this question is about analysis of plain text. We have relational data in relational database tables with lots of relationships.

Answer (score 1):

check out [greenplum](http://www.gopivotal.com/products/pivotal-greenplum-database)

We have 2 types of big data solutions:

1 is based on hadoop which supports data storage at PB levels

2 is based on greenplum for real time data analysis on smaller data scale.